# Show the details of an administrator only when the corresponding radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a page to edit the administrators of a post.
In this page there are some radio buttons. Each radio button corresponds to a administrator of a post. When a radio button is selected the details of that administrator are populated in the form fields

The issue is that when the user accesses this edit administrators of a post page no radio button should be checked so I don't have the "checked" property in the radio buttons. This is ok.

But although no radio button is checked, in the form fields are appearing by default the details of the last created administrator when the page is accessed at first. Then if I select other admin appears the details of that selected admin but when the page is acccessed at first and no radio button is checked in the form fields appears the details of the last created administrator.

Do you know how to only show the details of an administrator when the corresponding radio button is selected?

**Full form:**

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('admins.update', ['id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @foreach($administrators $admin)
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="">
              {{$admin->name}}
            </label>
          </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_administrator"
             value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
          Create new administrator
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->name }}" name="name">
  </div>

  <!-- below I have more form fields like administrator name, email, etc -->

  <input type="submit" id="adminStoreButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/>
  <input type="submit" id="adminUpdateButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"/>
  </form>
```

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#adminStoreButton").hide();

    var admins = {!!  $admin !!}

    $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {

        if($(this).attr("id") == "create_administrator"){
            $("#adminUpdateButton").hide();
            $("#adminStoreButton").show();
            $("#edit_administrator").attr('action', '{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
        }
        else{
            $("#adminUpdateButton").show();
            $("#adminStoreButton").hide();
            $("#edit_administrator").attr('action', '{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');

        }

        let id = $(this).attr("id");
        let data = admins.find(e => e.id == id) || {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            ...
            date: "",
        };

        $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
        $("input[name='email']").val(data.email);
       ...
        $("input[name='date']").val(moment(data.date).format('DD MMMM YYYY - HH:mm'));

    });
});
```

**// Administrator controller edit method that returns the view with the edit administrators form above:**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $administrators = Administrator::where('post_id', $id)->get();

    return view('administrators.edit')
        ->with('post', $post)
        ->with('administrators', $administrators));
}
```

**// update and store admin routes**

```
Route::get('post/edit/{id}/admins',    [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@edit', 'as'=>'admins.edit']);
Route::post('post/update/{id}/admins', [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@update', 'as'=>'admins.update']);
Route::post('post/store/{id}/admins', [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@store', 'as'=>'admins.store']);
```

**// Administrator controller update method:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
          ...
        ]);

        $adminToUpdate = Administrator::find($request->radiobutton);

        $adminToUpdate->name = $request->name;
        ...

        $adminToUpdate->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**// Administrator controller store method:**

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $post = Post::find($id);

    Administrator::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'post_id' => $post->id
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Add `autocomplete="off"`  to your form inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i get the same issue.

Comment: Did you consider switch your javascript logic into a ajax request? If yes, let me know and possibly i could make the logic for you. In my opinion,  it would allow you do what you want in a easier way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, but I already tried to convert this working example to ajax but Im in doubt how to do that properly. I had this "$("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {
                let id = $(this).attr("id");

                $.get('post/edit/'+ id+ '/admins', function(administrators) {

                });
            });" but Im in doubt if its correct and how to, after get the administrators details, populate the form fields with the selected administrator (radio button) details.

Comment: did you try @MajidFouladpour suggestion?? you should try it first to prevent form cached.

Comment: `$administrators = Administrator::where('post_id', $id)->get();` and then you loop `$administrators` in the view. can 1 post have multiple administrators?

Comment: if 1 post can have multiple admin. What the purpose of choose 1 of them via radiobutton?

Comment: Thanks. One post can have multiple admins, each admin is listed in a radio button when the radio button is selected it allows for the user to edit each selected administrator, the form fields are populated so the user can check the admin current details and then change the details and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **value** attribute of your fields (name, email, etc) should initially be blank. You don't need

```
value="{{ $admin->name }}"
```

on initial load, since you are setting the value in the radio button click event. Instead, it should be:

```
value=""
```

as in:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" value="" name="name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest get data of admin from ajax through backed and then fill into form.

```
let id = $(this).attr("id");
```

you have a admin id , create new route that accept id and return admin data into json

and then fill data through

```
 $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
 $("input[name='date']").val(data.date);
```

if any problem face do comment i help you

Comment: Thanks, but for example, in this part "var admins= {!!  $admin!!}" the controller sends to the view the array "admins" that already has all the administrators of the post, so its necessary ajax? And when a radio button is clicked it works the details of that selected administrator appears in the form fields. The issue is that when this page is accessed at first the form fields are populated with details of the last created administrator but no radio buttton (administrator) is selected, so the form fields should be empty.

Comment: you can do empty all the field of model close event

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain how to do that?

Comment: $("#myModal").on("hidden", function () {
  $('#result').html('yes,result');
});

Comment: Thanks, but I didnt understand. Can you explain better?

Comment: as i understand you want to clear form if no radio button is selected right ?

Comment: yes, and only show the details when some radio button (admin) is selected.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER**

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('admins.update', ['id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="hide-first">
        @foreach($administrators $admin)
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                   {{$admin->name}}
                </label>
            </div>
         @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_administrator"
         value="option2">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
           Create new administrator
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->name }}" name="name">
     </div>
     <!-- below I have more form fields like administrator name, email, etc -->
     <input type="submit" id="adminStoreButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/>
     <input type="submit" id="adminUpdateButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.hide-first).hide();

    $("#adminStoreButton").hide();

    var admins = {!!  $admin !!}

    $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {

        $('.hide-first).show();

        if($(this).attr("id") == "create_administrator"){
            $("#adminUpdateButton").hide();
            $("#adminStoreButton").show();
            $("#edit_administrator").attr('action','{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
        }
        else{
            $("#adminUpdateButton").show();
            $("#adminStoreButton").hide();
            $("#edit_administrator").attr('action','{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');

        }

        let id = $(this).attr("id");
        let data = admins.find(e => e.id == id) || {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            ...
            date: "",
        };

        $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
        $("input[name='email']").val(data.email);
       ...
        $("input[name='date']").val(moment(data.date).format('DD MMMM YYYY - HH:mm'));

     });
});
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Reason is when you are redirecting back its already fetching the last stored data with the get route of the edit function. Try not pass the id and check are the form/fields coming.

Instead of redirecting back try redirect to a path i.e

Use

```
return redirect('post/edit//admins');
```

instead of

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: What happens if u do this return redirect('post/edit//admins');

Comment: Thanks, I get the same issue, when "proj.test/post/edit/2/admins" is accessed the last created admin details appear on the form fields.

Comment: Do not pass the id 2, pass without id.

Comment: When u switch the radio button u can do api call or do a page reload by passing the id

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears "page cannot be found" because in the routes I also pass the id and it seems that it is necessary because its necessary to edit the administrators of a specific post, because the administrators are the administrators of a specific post, in this case of the post "2".

Comment: In this case i would suggest you bring data through api call, the id passed is 2 and maybe thats the last edited post isnt it, or u can redirect to show page and then come back to edit when u have to edit the specific post.

Comment: Thanks but Im not understanding well, I dont have any api. A user can manage the posts that he creates. In this case the user accessed the post with "2" that its a post that he created to edit the administrators that can also edit that post. The controller returns an array "->with('administrators', $administrators));" with all administrators of a specific post. The view receives this array and show each admin based on radio button selection. The only issue is that by default it appears when the page is acessed "proj.test/post/edit/2/admins" the details of the last createad admin

Comment: but no radio button is checked so it should not show any info in the form fields, just when a radio button is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166190/discussion-between-jigs1212-and-jon).

Comment: is the last created admin for the post with id 2 ?

Comment: When "proj.test/post/edit/2/admins" is accessed the edit form appears populated with the details of the last created administrator for the post with id "2".

Comment: Updated answerplease check the same

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it appears the same issue. The forms are filled with the last created admin details. And with that when user acesses "proj.test/post/edit/2/admins"  the only visible radio button is "create new admin". But all radio buttons (admins) should be visible and then the form fieds should only show the details of a specific admin when the corresponding radio button is selected and not when the page is accessed and no radio button is checked.

Comment: Can i collabrate using github so i can help u ahead.